# DAX Running Running Total Based on None Date Columns

Tags: dax, inventory, cumulative-sum, inventory-management

I need to do a running total and filter by two none date fields.

All data is in a single table that is used to house Cycle Times for Part Numbers at each of their respective steps.  This table contains a record for each combination of Step and Part.  I need to get a running total for Cycle Times on all complete and current steps.

For example in the [Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNNjm.png), if you were to go to CycleHoursComplete at StepNo 40 I need it to = 2.86 or the sum of StepCycleHours with StepNo's <= the StepNo for the given record.

Currently "CycleHoursComplete" = CALCULATE( SUM ( Routing[StepCycleHours] ) , GROUPBY(Routing, Routing[PartNo]), (Routing[StepNo] <= Routing[StepNo] )), and that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do running totals with non-date fields as long as you have a numerical identifier to sort by, such as an ID column or in your case, the StepNo column.

You just need to use a combination of FILTER and EARLIER functions. Here's the DAX:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM([StepCycleHours]),ALL(Cycle),Cycle[StepNo]<=EARLIER(Cycle[StepNo]))
```

Note my table is called "Cycle"- you would need to replace that with your table name (Routing).

I noticed you tried to use a similar logic as the one I pasted above in the formula, but you forgot to use EARLIER, which is crucial to create row-level context.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about grouping the SUM by part number?  I have hundreds of PartNo's included in this table so when I run this formula it seems to be SUMing all StepCycle Hours with Steps that are equal or lessor Step value.

Comment: Got It!  Thank you again for the help!      CycleHoursComplete = CALCULATE(                                                            SUM ( [StepCycleHours]),                                                            ALL(Routing) ,                                                            Routing[PartNo] = EARLIER(Routing[PartNo]),                                                  Routing[StepNo] <= EARLIER(Routing[StepNo])                                             )

Comment: Yes I think you've just figured it out. I think another way to handle that would be using ALLEXCEPT instead of ALL. ALLEXCEPT basically tells DAX "sum up everything, but keep these filters". In this case, you would have used ALLEXCEPT([PartNo]). But your current solution would certainly work!

Comment: Sorry, to be a little more exact.

Instead of using ALL(Routing), you could use ALLEXCEPT(Routing,Routing[PartNo]) and that should work.

Anyway, glad you figured it out! =)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!  You saved me hours!